# Chain of Implications for Continuity and Boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Consider the following definitions:

> >
>   1). Somewhere Locally Bounded:

$\exists p \in X, \exists \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall q \in X: d(p,q)< \delta \Rightarrow d(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon$.

> >
>   2). Locally Bounded:

$\forall p \in X, \exists \epsilon_p < \infty, \exists \delta_p >0, \forall q \in X : d(p,q)<\delta \Rightarrow d(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon$.

> >
>   3). Continuous:

$\forall p \in X, \exists \epsilon >0 \exists \delta_{p,\epsilon} >0, \forall q \in X :
d(p,q)<\delta \Rightarrow d(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon$.

> >
>   4). Uniformly Continuous:

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta_\epsilon >0, \forall p \in X, \forall q \in X:
d(p,q)< \delta \Rightarrow d(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon$.

> >
>   5). Lipschitz Continuous:

$\exists C>0, \forall \epsilon >0 \forall p \in X, \forall q \in X:
d(p,q)< \frac{\epsilon}{C} \Rightarrow d(f(p),f(q))< \epsilon$.

Alternatively, we can also write

$\forall \delta>0, \forall p,q \in X, d(p,q)<\delta \Rightarrow d(f(p),f(q))< C \cdot \delta$.

What I am asked to do is to find 4 examples of $(X,Y,f)$ showing $(5) \nLeftarrow (4) \nLeftarrow (3) \nLeftarrow (2) \nLeftarrow (1)$.

Here is my attempt at the complete solution:

$(5) \nLeftarrow (4)$.

Not all uniformly continuous functions are Lipschitz. 
Let us consider a continuous function on a compact set which has a vertical asymptote. Let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ on $[-1,1]$. Since $[-1,1]$ is compact, we have uniform continuity. But for $x_n= \frac{-1}{n^3}$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{n^3}$, we have

$\displaystyle {|\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n}| = |\frac{\frac{-2}{n}}{\frac{-2}{n^3}}| = n^2}$. However there is no $C$ such that $n^2 \leq C$ for all $n$, so the function $f$ cannot be Lipschitz continuous.

$(4) \nLeftarrow (3)$.

Continuity does not imply Uniform Continuity.
Let $f(x)=x^2$. This function is continuous, but not uniformly over $I=(0,\infty)$.

$\forall x_0 \in I, \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall x \in I$, such that 
$|x-x_0|< \delta \Rightarrow |x^2-x_0^2|< \epsilon$.

Let us fix $x_0$ and let $a=x_0+1$ and $\delta = \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2a})$.
Choose $x\in I$. Assuming $|x-x_0|< \delta$, we have $|x-x_0|<1, \quad x<x_0+1=a.$ So we get

$|x^2-x_0^2|= |(\frac{1}{\delta}+\frac{\delta}{2})^2-(\frac{1}{\delta})^2| = |\frac{1}{\delta^2} +1+ \frac{\delta^2}{4} - \frac{1}{\delta^2}| = 1+ \frac{\delta^2}{4} > 1 = \epsilon$ as required.

$(3) \nLeftarrow (2)$

Locally Bounded does not imply Continuity.

Let $f(x)= \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$. Then we have that $f(x)$ is locally bounded, say by (1,3), but $f(x)$ is not continuous at 2.

$(2) \nLeftarrow (1)$

For the last implication, I do not know how to start.

This is what I have so far, please feel free to correct any technical errors. I apologize for the very long post, but I have been struggling with this problem for a while now and would like to finally solve it.

As always, any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your $3)\not\Leftarrow 2)$ example, try the **Dirichlet Function**:
$$
D(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc}
1 & :x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & :x\not\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{array}\right.
$$
It tends to be great for continuity counterexamples, as it is discontinuous everywhere (and can be easily modified to be continuous, and even differentiable, at a finite or countable number of points). It should be obvious that is is bounded, as $|D(a)-D(b)|\leq 1$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

As for showing that $2)\not\Leftarrow 1)$, you only need to find a function that is not locally bounded at a single point. The easiest example is probably
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc}
0 & : x=0 \\
\frac{1}{x} & :x\neq0
\end{array}\right.$$
at $x=0$.

Comment: The issue here is that, technically, $f$ is *not defined* at those points, so you cannot choose your points $p$ as $2$ or $0$ respectively.

Comment: You're right, I've changed my examples.

Comment: I like your examples, actually, I was thinking of the Dirichlet function after I read the answer from @SomeMathStudent. For the second one, if I was interested in finding an $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ that would make the locally bounded condition fail, would it suffice to choose $x=0$ so that the distance is less than 1?

Comment: Since the conditions for locally bounded only require *existence*, you have to show that it fails for whatever $\epsilon, \delta$ you choose. So you need to show that for any $\epsilon$, you can choose an arbitrarily small $q$ such that $f(q)>\epsilon$.

Comment: More specifically, let $0<q<\min(\delta,\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to translate those definitions into a more 'geometrical' form.

$1)$ tells you that there is *some* fixed point $p$, where the for all $q$ close enough to $p$ the values $f(p),f(q)$ are not too far apart.

$2)$ tells you that for *every* point $p$, for some $q$ close enough to $p$ the values $f(p),f(q)$ are not too far apart.

So, a way to go about this is to notice that the first one is a purely *local* property - given a function which is constant on a certain interval and completely arbitrary on the rest, can still fulfill the first condition, whereas the second property is more *global* - at least, you have the local property everywhere on the domain.

I'd suggest looking at any not locally bounded function (you might want to think about rationals here, anything continuous will *not* work), and then switch it up with a locally bounded one somewhere - thus, you will get your contradiction.

Also, please note that your counterexample to $3)\Leftarrow 2)$ does not hold - the function $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}=x+2$ is perfectly continuous. Again, I'd recommend separating rational numbers and irrational numbers, and try to find a non-continuous, bounded function.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean by local and global properties. However, what do you mean by thinking about rationals? Like in your comment on my counterexample to $(3) \nLeftarrow (2)$, do you mean to define a function as, say 1 if it is rational and 0 if it is irrational?

Comment: For the second part, exactly that, yes. You are still bounded, but not continuous anymore. For the first part, you will need to modify this function a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the counterexample involving $f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ by specifying that $f(2) = \frac{5}{2}$.

Here is a function that is somewhere locally bounded but not locally bounded:
$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
x^q & x \mbox{ rational }, x= p/q \mbox{ with gcd}(p,q) = 1 \\
0 & x \mbox{ irrational }
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$f(x)$ is locally bounded at $x=0$ (or indeed at any point $x=p$ with $0 \leq p < 1$ thus it is somewhere locally bounded.  But $f(x)$ is not locally bounded:  Consider point $p$ at  $x=2$, where for points arbitrarily close to $p$, $f(x)$ is close to  $2^n$ for arbitrarily large $n$.